# My JQuery Chosen plugin not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I tried to add JQuery Chosen plugin to my website, but i can't make it work on a `<select>` , there are 2 classes in it that are from bootstrap, i tried to chosen-select on it, didn't work.

Heres the code, also, this page is being built in PHP.

**PHP-Dropbox**

```
<select class="form-control  bfh-countries chosen-select"  data-country="PT">
     <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
     <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
     <option value="AL">Albania</option>
     <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
     <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
     <option value="AD">
     (...)
```

and so on.

I added the plugin at the end of the file

**Import JS libray and plugin**

```
 <script src="<?php echo site_url('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js');?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo site_url('recursos/chosen/chosen.jquery.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>recursos/chosen/chosen.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function(){
            $(".chosen-select").chosen()
            });
        </script>
```

Why I can't load the plugin to the selector?

Comment: `<?php echo site_url('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js');?>  `should be `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js`  you are adding your site url infront of google api's url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your site's url infront of the google api's url , which is wrong and the jquery is not working for you at all. What `site_url` or `base_url` from codeigniter (which is your framework) does is , generate an url which is specified inside `config.php` file. if you put a path of any file inside these functions , it will become sort of :

`yoursite.com/your/another/path/file.js`

Change your code from this :

```
 <script src="<?php echo site_url('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js');?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo site_url('recursos/chosen/chosen.jquery.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>recursos/chosen/chosen.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function(){
            $(".chosen-select").chosen()
            });
        </script>
```

to this **Updated**:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo site_url('recursos/chosen/chosen.jquery.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
             $(".chosen-select").chosen();
            });
        </script>
```

and add this line to your `<head>` tag not in footer :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>recursos/chosen/chosen.css" />
```

By looking at the comment you have posted. Your path to the `chosen` plugin files are wrong. Please make sure you are targeting the right path.

Comment: Still nothing happen to the select element

Comment: @AndreFIlipe  show me the error inside console log  , the path : recursos/chosen/chosen.css and recursos/chosen/chosen.js exists ?

Comment: @AndreFIlipe  Show me the console errors , and also i have updated the code in answer , try to use that.

Comment: I placed the css import on the beggining, showed me a new error:
GET http://cbb.com.pt/natural/recursos/chosen/chosen.css
GET http://cbb.com.pt/natural/recursos/chosen/chosen.jquery.js 
GET http://cbb.com.pt/natural/recursos/chosen/chosen.css 
GET http://cbb.com.pt/natural/recursos/chosen/chosen.jquery.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please be sure about your paths , that you have specified , your path to the files are wrong.

Comment: The directory is right, only thing is missing is /natural/ behind, but the other css im using works fine with just "recursos"

Comment: @AndreFIlipe fix it then. this is one of your problems , other one was the jquery not loading problem.

Comment: Ok, i forgot to upload the new folder to the server, big mistake from my part

Comment: Okay , if i helped , consider accepting the answer , thanks.